# Implementation ideas for Web Service request for file transfer

Tags: web-services

I have a web service application written in Java - we use Glassfish as the Application Server.
And a client for the web service written in .NET.
As a result of a request made to the web service I would like to transfer a file from the server to the client. 
What would you recommend I use ?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be for your web service to return a string, which is a base64-encoded version of the file. Then the client would decode the string to get the file back.